# Convergence of sequences in co-finite and co-countable topological spaces

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, proof-verification

> I want to assess the convergence of the sequences
>
> $(x_n)$ such that $\{x_n|n \in \mathbb{N}\} = \{0,1,0,1,0,1,\ldots\}$
>
> And
>
> $(y_n)$ such that $\{y_n|n \in \mathbb{N}\} = \{1,2,3,4,5,6,\ldots\}$
>
> in
>
> $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{T}_{co-finite})$ and
>   $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{T}_{co-countable})$

**I have absolutely no clue how to proceed, but in any case here is my attempt**

**Attempt:**

> 1. $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{T}_{co-finite})$

(a) $(x_n)$ converges to $x$ if for every $U \in \mathcal{T}_{co-finite}$, $x \in U$, $\exists N \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $x_n \in U, \forall n \geq N$.

Let  $x \in U$, since $\mathbb{R}\backslash U$ is finite and $(x_n)$ takes on finitely many values, herefore $(x_n)$ converges to both $1$ and $0$

(b)  $(y_n)$ converges to $y$ if for every $U \in \mathcal{T}_{co-finite}$, $x \in U$, $\exists N \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $y_n \in U, \forall n \geq N$.

Suppose that $y \in U$, since $\mathbb{R}\backslash U$ is finite and $(y_n)$ contains infinitely many elements, therefore no element of the sequence $(y_n)$ is in $U$, hence $(y_n)$ does not converge

**Similarly, I have no idea how to proceed for $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{T}_{co-countable})$, please instruct!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's usually best to guess a limit and study open sets around that candidate.

Lets consider first the cofinite topology:

For $(x_n)$ a good candidate might be $1$. But we quickly find $\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$, an open set around $1$ such that there's no index after which every element of $(x_n)$ is in that open set. Showing that $(x_n)$ does not converge to $1$. Similarly we get $(x_n)$ does not converge to $0$ or to any other real number.

For $(y_n)$ guessing a candidate is not so obvious, so lets just guess arbitrarily, lets say $50$. Any open set $U$ around $50$ is missing only finite elements of $\mathbb{R}$ (i.e. it's cofinite), so there must be an index $N$ such that $n\geq N \implies y_n\in U$, otherwise there would be infinitely many natural numbers (elements of $(y_n)$) not contained in $U$ (i.e. it wouldn't be cofinite). This is, $(y_n)$ converges to $50$. We see there's nothing special about $50$ and actually $(y_n)$ converges to every real number.

For cocountable topology proceed in similar fashion, find open sets to try to separate your candidate limit to the sequence or figure out that you can't find them.

Comment: Okay I see. Very nice approach

Comment: In your second explanation, what if an open set around $U$ is of the form $\mathbb{R} \backslash \{q_1,\ldots, 50, \ldots, q_n\}$, where $q_1, \ldots, q_n$ are finitely many rationals?

Comment: What about it? It's missing at most $n$ elements of $(y_n)$ and so you can find an index after which every element of $(y_n)$ falls into that set. It might help clear things up to know that we actually proved a more general claim: In $(\mathbb{R}, \tau _{cofinite})$, If $(p_n)$ is a sequence with no repetitions, then $(p_n)$ converges to every real number.

Comment: Oh okay, sorry I was thinking of the case $\dfrac{1}{n}$ in which we do not know if the sequence will converge to 0, but this sequence definitely has an index that will converge to 50, so it is good

Answer (score 3):

Co-finite:

First sequence:

If $x \notin \{0,1\}$, then U = $\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0,1\}$ is a neighbourhood of $x$, so ...

If $x=1$, then $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ is a neighbourhood of $x$. Can be find $N$ as needed? Similar reasoning for $x=0$.

Show that if $p \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R} \setminus F$ where $F$ is finite, almost all $y_n \notin F$, so..

Co-countable:

The first sequence is already decided by the co-finite case (why?).

The second one: for any $p$ we consider $N = \{1,2,3,4,\dots\} \setminus \{p\}$ which is countable and $p \in \mathbb{R} \setminus N$, which is open, and contains at most one element of the sequence ...

Comment: @Crostul fixed. Thanks.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Thanks, topology addict